# Virtuoso: What happens when I get 'Checkpoint removed ** MB of remapped pages, leaving * MB'

Tags: sparql, freebase, virtuoso

I am loading freebase files into virtuoso. I have *88* folders. Every folder contains *4* files. I divided the files such way because I only have *8 GB* of RAM.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..88}
do
  isql 1111 dba dba exec="ld_dir('/data/data/${i}', '*.nt', 'http://freebase.com');"
  isql 1111 dba dba exec="rdf_loader_run();" 
  isql 1111 dba dba exec="checkpoint;"
  isql 1111 dba dba exec="commit WORK;"
  isql 1111 dba dba exec="checkpoint;"
  isql 1111 dba dba exec="delete from DB.DBA.load_list;"
done
```

---

## Virtuoso.ini

```
# each buffer caches a 8K page of data and occupies approx. 8700 bytes of memory
# it's suggested to set this value to 65 % of ram for a db only server
# so if you have 32 GB of ram: 32*1000^3*0.65/8700 = 2390804
# default is 2000 which will use 16 MB ram
[Database]
MaxCheckpointRemap = 150000 (I have 8GB of RAM)
[TempDatabase]
MaxCheckpointRemap      = 2000
NumberOfBuffers          = 170000
MaxDirtyBuffers          = 130000
```

---

## Message

Checkpoint removed 628 MB of remapped pages, leaving 31 MB. Duration     31.21 s.  To save this time, increase MaxCheckpointRemap and/or set Unremap quota to 0 in ini file.

---

## Question

Why am I getting this message? and does it affect the loading process and building of the database?

---

## update

```
    #!/bin/bash
   
    #clear list
    isql 1111 dba dba exec="delete from DB.DBA.load_list;"
    #load data
    isql 1111 dba dba exec="ld_dir('/data/data, '*.gz', 'http://freebase.com');"
    isql 1111 dba dba exec="set isolation='uncommitted';"
    isql 1111 dba dba exec="rdf_loader_run();" 
    #checkpoint
    isql 1111 dba dba exec="checkpoint;"
    isql 1111 dba dba exec="commit WORK;"
    isql 1111 dba dba exec="checkpoint;"
```

---

## virtuoso.ini

```
MaxCheckpointRemap       = 150000 (8GB RAM)
# Uncomment next two lines if there is 4 GB system memory free
NumberOfBuffers          = 340000
MaxDirtyBuffers          = 250000
# I have 6 cores
ThreadsPerQuery         = 4
AsyncQueueMaxThreads        = 10
#NO THREADS LEFT IN THE QUEUE
ThreadCleanupInterval       = 0
ThreadThreshold         = 0
#check point every 30 minutes.
CheckpointInterval      = 30
```

Comment: a couple of weird things i thought i should mention: your `virtuoso.ini` contains a comment snippet that is _ancient_. If you have a current virtuoso version you should use a more up to date default ini file and modify it. If not: update virtuoso!

Comment: you seem to have mixed up the important settings for `NumberOfBuffers` of your `[Database]` section with `MaxCheckpointRemap`!

Comment: In the bash-script you run `rdf_loader_run()` 88 times. You should actually be able to only run all the `ld_dir` lines in the loop as they only register the files to be loaded and then run the `rdf_loader_run` once! This should be way faster. Even more: you could just run `ld_dir_all` and get rid of the loop altogether. You don't have to split the files up into chunks that fit into memory as they're stream processed. So as long as your `virtuoso.ini` settings are right Virtuoso should handle all of that on its own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best explained in the [virtuoso docs](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com:8889/doc/html/CHECKPOINT.html#checkpointparams), but in short:

> The MaxCheckpointRemap parameter in the virtuoso.ini file controls how
>   many pages may be stored on a page other than their logical page.

This means that increasing the parameter will save you work (and time) on a checkpoint but reduces the data locality feature (data that is inserted together is saved close together).

Comment: Can you please check the update. Let me know please if it's right

Comment: looks much better, even though i don't know where you get the idea from that manually disabling and re-enabling indexing gives you any benefit. usually the `rdf_loader_run()` function does the necessary things to make the import fly. Checkpointing doesn't "clear" the RAM (free RAM is wasted RAM). A checkpoint is forcing the database state to be written on disk in a single consistent image, emptying the transaction log, etc. (http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/checkpoint.html ) During bulk import you probably don't want to do this every minute.

Comment: **where you get the idea from that manually disabling and re-enabling indexing gives you any benefit**
https://github.com/dbpedia/dbpedia-tutorial/blob/master/scripts/virtuoso/load_data.sql . Man you are good sheesh thank you